# Cygwin Gcc - Access

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, windows-vista, cygwin

I'm currently on Windows Vista Basic.

I have recently started on Eclipse, and for that I was required to install **cygwin**.
After that I made an edit in the **PATH** environment variable in "My Computer>Properties>Advanced Settings". In order to check the functionality, I started cmd-prompt and types

```
C:>gcc
```

This gives the following output: ACCESS IS DENIED

I know it's a security permission problem, but I don't know where exactly to do the change in the security settings. Last time I tried it started showing "error-illegal operation" and some error code.

Comment: Please put some effort into forming complete sentences, using punctuation, and properly spelling words. This is just plain lazy and rude to people who might otherwise help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can not use gcc in your cmd. you must use it in cygwin shell that installed when you install cygwin

Comment: You cannot use Cygwin gcc in cmd. MinGW(-w64) gcc is just another Windows executable.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use gcc without using the cygwin shell !!**

But you will probably end up with some configuration problems,
such as not having the correct dll's in the right places.
Another common error that can occur, is if you have multiple instances
of cygwin installed, the search paths get confused and the gcc system
can't find relevant compiler or tries to use the wrong compiler.

All the same this is very possible, I've done it myself hundreds of time,
when testing compilers I have written.

You might want to try invoking 'cc1.exe' for c, or 'cc1plus.exe' for c++,
remember to copy the cygwin dll's into the same directory as cc1 or cc1plus,

Other than that it could be your user account permissions.

Hope this helps.

/Tony